# How to export all definition symbols in a file in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, package

My lisp file contains about 50 function and macro definitions. At the head of the file is:

```
(defpackage :utils
  (:use :common-lisp))

(in-package :utils)

; ...  ~50 defuns/defmacros follow along with some other code
```

I want to export all these 50 definitions. But no other symbols.
To write them all out in :export clauses inside defpackage seems very tedious.

I tried getting the necessary symbols by using loop's facility for listing symbols in a package. But both "symbol" and "present-symbol" don't output the needed definition symbols. I could somehow subtract "external-symbols" and inherited symbols. But this seems like the kind of thing everyone would need and there should be an established easy solution. I looked around and haven't found a straightforward answer.

**How do I export all the definition symbols without having to write them out individually and manually?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## scan symbols

You can scan all symbols and export **all** that have a function binding (this includes macro names):

```
(defun export-fbound-symbols (package)
  "export symbols with function bindings"
  (do-symbols (s package)
    (when (fboundp s)
      (export s package))))
```

This is usually not a very good idea: good software engineering practice is to *limit* the set of public interfaces.

## be more selective

You can redefine [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) and [`defmacro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defmac.htm) so that they automatically export their definienda.
See [`exporting.lisp`](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/src/exporting.lisp) in [CLISP](http://clisp.org/impnotes/modules.html#exporting). E.g.,

```
(defmacro define-function (name lambda-list &body body)
  `(progn
     (export ',name)
     (defun ,name ,lambda-list ,@body)))
```

Note that this ignores the possibility of `(defun (setf foo) (...) ...)`.

Comment: I've seen DEFINE for an exporting DEFUN variant and DEFINE-MACRO for an exporting DEFMACRO variant.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not something everyone needs.  Usually, you'd export them as you write (and actually need) them.

I'd probably use an ad hoc keyboard macro for this.  You could also write a little Lisp function to read your file form by form and output the relevant symbols for copy-paste.